# How to traverse through two lists

Tags: python, list, comparison

This will be applied in recursive tree function, but I thought i can put it into perspective with two basic lists:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,3]
```

I would like to use iteration or recursion to simply traverse through each item in both 'a' and 'b', and ensure that all item are of equal value.

I've tried:

```
for i in a:
    for g in b:
        if i == g:
           return True
```

But this obviously does not work. My assignment is to compare two trees to make sure all subtrees are of equal value and in equally placed in the same spots.

Comment: There must be a better purpose to this. Why can't you just check `a == b`?

Answer (score 3):

```
all(x == y for x, y in itertools.izip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=object()))
```

should best ensure the result you want.  The `fillvalue` is set to a new `object()`, a **sentinel** guaranteed not to compare equal to anything else -- and `izip_longest` **pads** the shortest of the two sequences with that sentinel, thus guaranteeing no "false positive" for equality when comparing sequences of different lengths.

Answer (score 2):

In simple way, list itself can be compared to be identical or not:

```
In[2]: a = [1,2,3]
In[3]: b = [1,2,3]
In[4]: a==b
Out[4]: True
In[5]: c = [2,1,3]
In[6]: a==c
Out[7]: False
```

Suppose you will only use the same size trees of a and b, you have to go through two trees by index:

```
all_equal = True
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i]!=b[i]:
        all_equal = False
        break
```

Comment: The least complicated, and the most efficient. +1

Comment: Only checks for the length of `a`. As @Akavall said "This evaluates to True even if `a=[1,2,3]` and `b=[1,2,3,4]`"

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> all(x == y for (x, y) in itertools.izip(a, b))
True
```

Comment: This evaluates to `True` even if `a=[1,2,3]` and `b=[1,2,3,4]`.

Comment: Sure, but a length check is cheap and easy.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, yes, but `izip_longest` is just as fast and more elegant than truncating `izip`, see my answer.